# Show that this $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{n+1}{n^2+1})^2$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying to solve this question from exercise: Show that this infinite series converges using comparison test.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{n+1}{n^2+1})^2$$.

What I do is the following: Observe that $$\lim_{n->\infty} (\frac{n+1}{n^{2}+1})^2= \lim_{n->\infty} (\frac{1+1/n}{1+1/n^2})^2 = 1$$So we can use comparison test. So, we need to choose either the numerator or denumerator to be divergence or convergence. I choose $a_n= (n+1)^2$. The partial sum of this series is: $$s_n=2^2+3^2+4^2+....+(n+1)^2$$ So, $$s_n+1=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2(n+1)+1}{6}$$Now, if you take the limit of this series, you get: $\infty$, so the infinite series diverges. But it should be converges. What is wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Going from the left to the middle part inside the brackets of your line $\lim_{n->\infty} (\frac{n+1}{n^{2}+1})^2= \lim_{n->\infty} (\frac{1+1/n}{1+1/n^2})^2 = 1$, you divide the numerator by $n$ but the denominator by $n^2$, so it's *not* correct.

Comment: Intuitively, the terms $1$ are negligible in front of powers of $n$, so that $\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\to\frac1n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac {n+1} {n^{2}+1} \leq \frac 2 n$. Hence the series is dominated by $\sum \frac 4  {n^{2}}$ which is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that:
$$
\left(\frac{n + 1}{n^2 + 1}\right)^2 \leq \left(\frac{n + n}{n^2}\right)^2 = \frac{4}{n^2}
$$
It's well known that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. Hence, your series must also converge.

Answer (score 2):

You made two mistakes.

The first is "a typo",

$$\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\ne\frac{1+\dfrac1n}{1+\dfrac1{n^2}}.$$

The second is more conceptual: when the general term is a fraction, you cannot discuss convergence/divergence just by looking at the numerators or denominators. Because

$$\frac ab=\frac{2a}{2b}=\frac{0.001a}{0.001b}=\cdots$$ and the magnitudes of the numerator and denominator are relative and may not be considered separately.

Finally, you did not use a comparison test at all.

Comment: Thank Yves for your comments. I should say I used "Limit Form of Comparison Test" which says let there be two infinite series of positive real numbers such that $a_n/b_n$ tends to finite non-zero limit as $n -> \infty$, then either the infinite series $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge or diverge

Comment: So, I understand that I shouldn't separate the $(n+1)/(n^2+1)$ as $a_n=n+1$ and $b_n=n^2+1$ since the whole series is fraction < 1 and >0. Because I was trying to use limit form of comparison test.

Comment: @user777: if I tell you that $\frac ab=5$, how much is $b$ ?

Comment: It is difficult to know since you have unknown value of a. So, b=a/5.

Comment: @user777: do you see my point now ?

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the fact that
$$\left(\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{n^2+1}+\frac{2n}{(n^2+1)^2} \leq \frac{2}{n^2+1}<\frac{2}{n^2} $$
granting that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right)^2 \leq \frac{\pi^2}{3}.$$
For more accurate approximations, you may use the fact that by defining $f(n)$ as $\frac{6 n+1}{6 n^2-8 n+7}$ we have that $\left(\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right)^2$ is very close to $f(n)-f(n+1)$, such that the previous series approximately equals $1+f(2)=\frac{28}{15}$.